# Webpack/Babel changes how data is assigned to variables in foreach loops depending on their scope - why?

Tags: reactjs, foreach, scope, webpack, babeljs

I've built a simple React component. Consider this code:

```
var myTempColor = {};
Object.keys(artistListing).sort().forEach((song, index) => {
    myTempColor["color"] = stringToColor(artistName + song);
    //use myTempColor variable to apply styling to an element
});
```

stringToColor is a globally declared function. Normally, I'd expect this code to work, but the result after webpack is that all songs in artistListing are given the same color. A change in artistName (which is a prop passed by a parent component) changes the color, but changes in the song variable seem ignored. Now if I change the code to this:

```
Object.keys(artistListing).sort().forEach((song, index) => {
    var myTempColor = {};
    myTempColor["color"] = stringToColor(artistName + song);
    //use myTempColor variable to apply styling to an element
});
```

everything works as expected. So it seems that by declaring the variable within the loop itself, webpack is prevented from doing some form of optimisation that led to the undesired behavior.

My questions are what type of optimisations cause these sorts of bugs? Are there other, similar pitfalls to watch out for when using Webpack? As someone who's not used to his javascript being transpiled, I'm really curious about what's happening under the hood here.

Answer (score 0):

The [Babel homepage](http://babeljs.io/) provides a transpiler right there in the browser, here is the output for your 2 code snippets (using es2015 and react preset):

```
"use strict";

var myTempColor = {};
Object.keys(artistListing).sort().forEach(function (song, index) {
    myTempColor["color"] = stringToColor(artistName + song);
    //use myTempColor variable to apply styling to an element
});
```

and

```
"use strict";

Object.keys(artistListing).sort().forEach(function (song, index) {
    var myTempColor = {};
    myTempColor["color"] = stringToColor(artistName + song);
    //use myTempColor variable to apply styling to an element
});
```

As for Webpack, you haven't included any webpack configuration, nor have you shown how modules are imported/exported in your codebase, so there isn't really anything to help debug the issue, if you provide more details I'll update the answer.

That said, it is unlikely Webpack has optimized your code unless you explicitly configured it to.